# Gettext tool to use the translation in one language as the key for translation in another language

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, gettext

Is there a tool to do what I'm suggesting in the question title?  Consider the following scenario, where the `msgid` is `"%s minutes left"`, the `msgstr` in English is, well, the same, and `msgstr` in another Language is `"bla %s bla"`.  Someone in marketing decides that in English the string should be `"%s minutes left, hurry up!"`.  What do I do?  On the one hand, I can change the `msgid`.  On the plus side, it becomes evident that the translation in Language needs to be updated; but the string change requires a developer to update a source file, which doesn't sound like good use of the developer's time when there are so many features to implement and time is scarce.  On the other hand, a translator could update the msgstr in English, so as to match the marketing person's request, but then how do I notify translators that they have to update their translation?  Also, all they see is the `msgid`, which hasn't changed.  So how to I tell them what the actual string is?

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: For a tool making translating easier, you could look into [poedit](http://poedit.net/) (since you didn't mention it), but i don't think it handle the 'You need to change translation since original text changed'.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common situation and – for better or for worse - is pretty much built into Gettext's intended workflow.

The normal workflow being:

```
source code > extract to POT > generate PO > translate PO
```

An amend to source text would then be:

```
edit source > extract new POT > merge into PO > review fuzzy strings
```

The `msgmerge` command line tool allows you to merge an amended POT file with already-translated PO files. This will mark any translations that had their source language altered as **Fuzzy**, meaning that translators might want to check again if their translation is still accurate.

```
msgmerge old.po changes.pot -o new.po
```

The POEdit program also has this function via a "Update from POT" menu option which I suspect may be using the msgmerge program in the background.

As @deceze has pointed out, using "machine IDs" separates source strings from translations and can avoid such problems. Although this is how many other localisation platforms work, it is not really how Gettext is intended to work (square peg, round hole etc.)

Perhaps worth mentioning though is that you can use "Extracted comments" feature to convey further information to translators. In the PO/POT file they are indicated with a "#. " prefix. The `xgettext` program extracts these from your source code, but you could also maintain them manually.

For example, if you wanted to maintain an English PO file (for your marketing people to edit) and also use machine IDs in your code, you could have something like this:

```
#. %s minutes left
msgid "time-nag-minutes-left"
msgstr "%s minutes left, hurry up!"
```

Where line 1 is your original source code comment showing the initial English, the second line is your machine ID and the third line is your marketing people editing the "translation" without any need to edit the source code again.

I'm not recommending this - it's non-standard and your translators may be used to Gettext working the way it's supposed to. It's an option though.

Answer (score 1):

Working with gettext, you have two options:

1. Use "string ids" in the source and provide all the UI text in PO files. E.g.:

   ```
   msgid "FRONTPAGE_SALES_CALL_TO_ACTION"
   msgstr "Buy now, buy often!"
   ```

   This has the advantage that you can change UI text purely by editing PO files, not needing to touch code. It has the disadvantage that your users will see nonsense in the UI for missing translations, and that the UI code is more abstract/meaningless and may make it somewhat harder to work with/prototype properly etc. It also introduces complexities in working with translators, as you mention yourself.
2. Use the literal UI text in your code and only supply translations for it in PO files.

   In this case you should *not* have a PO file for your source language, where each `msgid` and `msgstr` are identical. That's just redundant.

   If you're using this style (and apparently you are), then any actual change of text must happen at the source. The source code is your canonical UI; if you're changing the meaning of a message, it's actually a change in the UI so the UI code needs to be updated. You then sync that change with your PO files using `xgettext` (or similar tools), which propagates the change to all translation files and marks the changed string for translation (or even pulls out an existing translation if available).

You should not get into the habit of doing 2. but treating it like 1. That'll lead to a lot of confused *WTF?!* moments down the road.

If you want to enable "front end people" to change text without needing to touch complex source code, you need to decouple your front end code better from your backend code. This is not necessarily the task of gettext, but of a better template system or otherwise better MVC separation.

Comment: Thanks for also making my statemente clearer.  I think you are particularly right about the decoupling, but I think that in any case someone who wants to change the text needs to edit a template file somewhere, and if they don't even wanna edit that, a developer must do it; could you agree with this?

Comment: Anyway your answer also made me see that my question title has little to do with the question main body, my bad.  I think I'm sticking with either (1) or (2), but a tool to use somewhat other than msgid for the source language would be really useful in any case.

Comment: Actually, I want to amend my point 1.: you should never ever do that, it's not what PO files are for. Because if you do that, you'll have to separately communicate what "FRONTPAGE_SALES_CALL_TO_ACTION" is supposed to say to the translators. A translator cannot translate this message on its own merits. It breaks the whole gettext workflow. (Basically the bigger picture of the problem you mention yourself.) Also, changing a sentence *may* have repercussions beyond just that single sentence. Maybe you have to reflow the UI, make a button bigger etc. Any UI change needs a UI expert to do it.

Comment: ... If letting non-devs change the UI is a priority for your company (depending on the use case that's a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do), you should have a whole layer in your system that allows people to do that. E.g. you have those "FRONTPAGE_SALES_CALL_TO_ACTION" tokens in your UI which then gets extracted into a format that's easy to work with for non-devs which then gets put through a gettext workflow. Or have a WYSIWYG CMS system specifically for that. But don't use gettext as that middle layer.

Comment: Yes, if it were possible I wouldn't let non-devs work on the UI, but in fact, what I'm doing is adding a layer on top of gettext to enable non-devs to make changes, because that's what the company needs right now.  I guess that the kind of functionality that I was looking for is something I'm going to provide in this outer layer...